# Unpacking an array and adding item to array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array in VBA that I would like to append, and it is the item of a dictionary. It is assigned like this:

```
dict.Add Key:=arr(i, 1), Item:=Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4), arr(i, 5), arr(i, 6), arr(i, 7), arr(i, 8))
```

However I understand that arrays in VBA are very static, and can't simply be appended. Is there a way for me to unpack the elements of the array, and then create a new array (with the new item) and assign it back as the dictionary's item?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way that you can anticipate the maximum length of the array so you can preallocate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ReDim with Preserve but only on a copy of the dictionary item. Apparently, redim'ming a variant array dictionary Item in place is not allowed..

```
Sub meh()
    Dim i As Long, itm As Variant, dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    dict.Add Key:=("a"), Item:=Array(1, 2, 3)

    For i = LBound(dict.Item("a")) To UBound(dict.Item("a"))
        Debug.Print dict.Item("a")(i)
    Next i

    itm = dict.Item("a")
    ReDim Preserve itm(LBound(itm) To UBound(itm) + 1)
    itm(UBound(itm)) = "new"
    dict.Item("a") = itm

    For i = LBound(dict.Item("a")) To UBound(dict.Item("a"))
        Debug.Print dict.Item("a")(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The 'redim preserve...' line gives me a syntax error. I've been over it many times and can't spot what's wrong.

Comment: I've found and bandaided the problem although I don't know is this is more trouble than it's worth.